# Convert ISO8061 Duration to a datetime or time value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some ISO8601 Durations (not to be confused with ISO601 datetime)

Here are some example valid values:

```
P1D
PT0H
PT11M
P1DT2H15M
PT10H11M
PT2H46M12S
```

the specification is here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Ideally, I would like to take these values and parse them as either time or datetime2 values
to make it easier to work with

I was able to brute force parse these using string functions but the code is complex and seems error prone hoping there was a better way?

```
with anchors as
(
SELECT
 dt[duration]
, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('D', dt.duration), 0) As DLocation
, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('T', dt.duration), 0) As TLocation
, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('H', dt.duration), 0) As HLocation
, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('M', dt.duration), 0) As MLocation
, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('S', dt.duration), 0) As SLocation
, LEN(dt.duration)             as TotalLength
FROM dbo.DurationTest dt
)
SELECT
     duration
    ,DaysValue = CAST(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(duration, 2, (DLocation - 2)), 0) as tinyint)
    ,HoursValue = CAST(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(duration, TLocation + 1, (HLocation - TLocation) - 1 ), 0) as tinyint)
    ,MinutesValue = CAST(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(duration, COALESCE(HLocation, TLocation) + 1, MLocation - COALESCE(HLocation, TLocation) - 1), 0) as tinyint)
    ,SecondsValue = CAST(ISNULL(SUBSTRING(duration, COALESCE(MLocation, TLocation) + 1, SLocation - COALESCE(MLocation, TLocation) - 1 ), 0) as tinyint)
FROM anchors
```

this code gets the values into days, hours, minutes and seconds. converting to either a int value to seconds or a datetime2 is pretty well documented from that. As pointed out in the comments a time data type will only work for values <24 so I've kind of given up on that.

for further context this data is coming from ADP payroll webservice and this field tracks the daily time entry you would think it would be less than 24hrs but I have some outliers in my dataset.

I've created the following enhancement request here (not sure if it will get traction or not):
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/557e5b51-1824-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198

Comment: And what do you expect when your "duration" value >= 24 hours? Datetime and related datatypes are not really substitutes for a true duration datatype. And it makes little sense to translate "36 hours" into an actual datetime value - you must artificially select a starting point as a base value to which you add "36 hours". Is there a better way? I guess it depends on how you intend to use these values.

Comment: ISO durations don't map to time data types because they're not a time-of-day thing, they're a measure of seconds in relation to some other event. Consider storing the conversion in int or bigint columns (probably the latter given that "years" is a thing).

Comment: While It would seem that sql needs a duration data type that not really what I'm after in this question it is more about parsing the data into a usable format. optimistically, for values < 24hrs I'd expect a a valid time value for values > 24 a datetime(2) with a 1900-01-01: SELECT CAST('2022-08-25 01:28:05.440' as time), CAST('01:28:05.440' as datetime2)

Comment: The only option is to parse this character by character. Alternatively, you could write a SQLCLR function which parses it using `XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan`, but that is pretty complex to write and doesn't work on SQL Azure

Comment: I've got it done all in SQL... right now, I have it so that it creates the duration as a datetime that can easily be added to a start date if this is for planning purposes.  Let me know if that's what you're looking for and I'll add the final touches tonight.  And it handles any things > than their normal time equivalents.  For example, it'll handle things like P200MT1000H1000M (although that seems silly but you never know).  And, it's pretty short for what it does.  I just need to know a little more about what output you really expect.

Comment: @JasonHorner - Please see comment above.  Forgot to tag you on it.

Comment: @JeffModen thanks I will update my code to provide my "working" example it handles most of what I need but it feels overly complex

Comment: @Charlieface that would be ideal but as you point out won't work on sqlazure. was kind of hoping that there would be some type of sqlxml based hack but didn't pursue it .

Comment: @JasonHorner - Thanks for posting your code.  Mines a fair bit more complex because I solved for the whole ISO standard including years and months and check the relational position of "M" according to "T" to determine if a value where for months or minutes.  I'll see if I can whittle it down but your code isn't so bad and it does show exactly what you want for an output.

Comment: @JasonHorner - I may have something interesting and easy if ADP never sends you anything with years, months, or weeks (and I can add weeks back in pretty easily if you think you'll need it).  Since this is supposed to return a "duration", would a return of decimal hours out to 6 decimal places suffice?  And, yeah..,. it does over 24 hours.

Comment: Actually, I said screw it and added weeks back in just to be on the safe side.  Unlike years and months, a week does have a fixed number of hours.  I still need to know if a decimal hours output to 6 places is ok.  If it is, I'll post what I came up with.

Comment: Never mind.  I just posted a possible solution that's pretty clean.  If the return isn't what your druthers are, it's really easy to change.

Comment: Unfortuantely, while it appears XQuery will accept `xs:duration` as a type, it will not allow arithmetic on it, nor allow conversion to any other type than a string, so you can't parse it out like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one working example.  Read the header for what it does but this one returns the ADP "ISO-Like" durations as Decimal Hours to 6 Decimal Places.  If you need something else instead, the changes will be quite simple to make.  Let me know.

Here's the iTVF (inline Table Valued Function).  Details are in the comments.  As so often happens, the comments are bigger than the code itself.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AdpDurToDecHours
/*********************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Convert ADP payroll webservice daily time entries (durations) from a
 subset of the ISO Duration notation to Decimal Hours.

 *** DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION IF YEAR AND/OR MONTH CAN BE PRESENT! ***
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Usage Examples:
--===== Convert a set of ADP time entries from a table.
 SELECT  st.SomeOtherColumns
        ,adp.DecimalHours
   FROM dbo.SomeTable st
  CROSS APPLY dbo.AdpDurToDecHours(st.AdpDur) adp
;
--===== Convert a single value from a variable.
 SELECT adp.DecimalHours FROM dbo.AdpDurToDecHours(@AdpDur) adp
;
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Dependencies:
 1. None
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Programmer Notes:
 1. DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION IF YEAR AND/OR MONTH CAN BE PRESENT!!!
 2. This code will fail with the following error if you pass it a 
    NULL, Empty String, or BLANK String. Other "non-ISO" compliant
    values may also fail or create improper output but such other 
    things have not been tested.  Ostensibly, the values passed should
    be compliant for proper returns.

   Msg 1014, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
   A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value.

 3. This code follows the ISO specification for durations except for
    "Year" and "Month", which have been intentionally excluded because
    they're "indeterminate" for durations unless combined with a 
    starting date.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 References:
 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations
 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479091/convert-iso8061-duration-to-a-datetime-or-time-value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - 25 Aug 2022 - Jeff Moden
        - Create and test PoP code.
 Rev 01 - 26 Aug 2022 - Jeff Moden
        - Exclude "Year" and "Month".
        - Convert output to Decimal Hours.
 Rev 02 - 27 Aug 2022 - Jeff Moden
        - Convert to documented function (iTVF).
*********************************************************************/
        (@AdpDur VARCHAR(36))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
 RETURN WITH
 --==== Creates an inline sequence generator
       S1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))S0(N))
,cteTally(N) AS (SELECT TOP(LEN(@AdpDur))
                      N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                   FROM S1 a,S1) --1 to 36 rows max
,cteLocateDurTypes AS
(--==== Find positions/lagging positions of the duration type tokens
 SELECT  DurType = SUBSTRING(@AdpDur,t.N,1)
        ,LN      = LAG(t.N,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY t.N)
        ,t.N
   FROM cteTally t
  WHERE SUBSTRING(@AdpDur,N,1) IN ('P','W','D','T','H','M','S')
)
,cteIsolateValue AS
(--==== Determine the value for each duration token present
 SELECT  DurType
        ,Value = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@AdpDur,LN+1,N-1-LN))
   FROM cteLocateDurTypes
)--==== Convert DurType Values to seconds and sum as Decimal Hours
 SELECT DecimalHours =  SUM(
                            CASE DurType
                            WHEN 'S' THEN Value
                            WHEN 'M' THEN Value*60
                            WHEN 'H' THEN Value*3600
                            WHEN 'D' THEN Value*86400
                            WHEN 'W' THEN Value*604800
                            ELSE 0
                            END
                        )/3600.0 
   FROM cteIsolateValue
;
GO
```

Here's a short test table based on what @JasonHorner posted with a few additions.

```
--===== Drop the test table if it exists to make reruns easier in SSMS
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DurationTest;
GO
--===== Create and populate the test table on-the-fly.
 SELECT  Duration = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36),v.Duration)
   INTO #DurationTest
   FROM (VALUES
        --(NULL)   --Causes Failure
        --,('')    --Causes Failure
        --,('  ')  --Causes Failure
         ('PT')    --It could happen
        ,('P1W')   --Added this entry
        ,('P1D')
        ,('PT1H')  --Added this entry
        ,('PT1M')  --Added this entry
        ,('PT1S')  --Added this entry
        ,('PT0H') 
        ,('PT10H') --Added this entry
        ,('PT11M')
        ,('P1DT2H15M')
        ,('PT10H11M')
        ,('PT2H46M12S')
        ,('P1W2DT12H46M12S') --Added this entry
        )v(Duration)
;
GO
```

Here's a test of the function using the test table as the source.

```
--===== Simple test
 SELECT *
   FROM #DurationTest dt
  CROSS APPLY dbo.AdpDurToDecHours(dt.Duration) adp
;
GO
```

And, finally, here are the results from the test.

[image]